# problem to configure sidebar in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I am creating a sidebar to manage my Sheet (I am new to development and I created it from video tutorials).
What I want is to have the data corresponding to the id entered in the input. I managed to have this data according to a predefined input but I don't see how to do that, when I enter my id in the input, it returns me the data corresponding to the entered id.
I also have an input to enter data. It works for the predefined input and I would like it to write to the range corresponding to the id entered above.

Here is the gs part of the sheet:

```
var SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  tmp.initialValue = initialValue();
  var html = tmp.evaluate();
  html.setTitle('Gestion des demandes')
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function initialValue(){
  return SHEET.getRange(2,1).getValue();
}

function getSecteur(){
  return SHEET.getRange(2,2).getValue();
}

function getZone(){
  return SHEET.getRange(2,3).getValue();
}

function getSalle(){
  return SHEET.getRange(2,4).getValue();
}

function setValue(inputValue){
  SHEET.getRange(2,5).setValue(inputValue);
}
```

Here is the html part of the sheet:

```
<body>
<h1 style="font-size:16px;text-align:center">Interface administrateur</h1>
<br>
<label for="input-box">Quel Id ?</label>
<input id="input-box" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label for="secteur">Secteur :</label>
<input id="secteur" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label for="zone">Zone :</label>
<input id="zone" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label for="salle">Salle :</label>
<input id="salle" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button id="get-value">Get value</button>
<br>
<br>
<label for="set-input">Quelle donnée à reporter </label>
<input id="set-input" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button id="set-value">Set value</button>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button>

<script>
  var initVal = <?= initialValue ?>;
  document.getElementById('input-box').value = initVal;

  document.getElementById('get-value').addEventListener('click',function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showSecteur).getSecteur();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showZone).getZone();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showSalle).getSalle();
  });

  function showSecteur(mySecteur){
    document.getElementById('secteur').value = mySecteur;
  }
  function showZone(myZone){
    document.getElementById('zone').value = myZone;
  }
  function showSalle(mySalle){
    document.getElementById('salle').value = mySalle;
  }

  document.getElementById('set-value').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('set-input').value;
    google.script.run.setValue(inputValue);
  });

</script>
```

And [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gBlXQjHuoybJ9cngGx6CD8-df3DqXtcB0l1r81niauA/edit?usp=sharing) is the link for the sheet.

Thanks in advance for your help, I am very grateful.

Comment: I said hello guys but i mistake and Edit don't work.... I'm really sorry about that

Comment: I'm not sure what set value is supposed to do, let me know if I got this right (you set the id and populates the form with the data): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AqJAjZ4z7_JL29vU2taxcIu0tYaA2DQlwh6eP1nbu8o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yes that's right, I want to provide the id in the first input ("Which id?"). The next three inputs are for information purposes to know the area, the zone and the room that correspond to the id entered. And then I want to fill in the range of column E (setValue) that corresponds to the id provided before by writing in the input "Which data to report?"

Comment: check out my sheet and let me know if I got it right

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. 
In your script, if you change the id in the input (50 for example), it does not show you the area, zone and room that correspond to this id. It still shows "Secteur 49", "Zone 49", and "Salle 49". What I would like is that if you enter 50 in the first input, it displays "Secteur 50", "Zone 50", and "Salle 50" (the area, zone and room that correspond to that id - which are on the same line).

Comment: And then, if you write something in the "Quelle donnée à reporter" input, it is reported in column E "Set Value", in the row corresponding to the id entered above. If you do the test on your script, it does not carry over any data and the fields above are set to undefined.